# Swap text so that it replaces a string with user inputs and loop through a textand replace the contents

Tags: javascript, html, user-input, swap

I want to swap text so that it replaces a string (ie "electric") within any given text that the user inputs in a form cell. Then loop through the span elements in the text and replace their contents with the input text.

```
function swap_text() {
    var input_text = document.getElementById("input_text").value;


    var spans = document.getElementById("text").getElementsByTagName("span");
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I have made it to the point to create the function, get the user input but not swapping it out with the user input value. For example i have a 500 word text, that I want the user to input "planet" and replaces all the words "earth" in the text.  Then loop through the span elements in the text and replace their contents with the input text. Sorry but I am extremely new with javascript, been working only with html.

Answer (score 0):

I think what might be confusing you is that `.getElementsByTagName("span")` returns an HTMLCollection, not an array.

One approach is to convert that to an array, then you can simply loop the array and set the text.

```js
function swapText() {
    const inputText = document.getElementById("input_text").value;

    const spans = document.getElementById("text").getElementsByTagName("span");

    Array.from(spans).forEach(span => {
        span.innerText = "some text"
    })
}
```

A few tips (although they are subject to preference):

1. By convention JavaScript is typically written using `camelCase`.
2. Use `const` instead of `var` if you don't plan to change the variable, it's helpful for other devs to read it and know that it won't change later.
3. Prefer `let` over `var` until you truely understand the
   difference between the two.

Comment: Sorry Steve, my mistake. It is actually connected with an HTML that's why I used the .getElementsByTagName("span")

Comment: Yeah thats fine, you do need to use that. Those functions that let you interact with HTML are actually browser APIs though, not native JS. So you just need to convert them to something that works the way you want it to with JS... i.e `Array.from()`

Answer (score 0):

The HTML the function is expected to be applied upon was loosely described but not actually provided by the OP. I hope it looks something like in the following snippet:

```js
const spans=document.querySelectorAll("#text span"),
 inp=document.querySelector("#repl");
inp.addEventListener("input",()=>spans.forEach(sp=>sp.textContent=inp.value));
```

```css
span {color:orange}
```

```html
<input id="repl" type="text" placeholder="enter new text for spans here!" size="20">
<h2>My text</h2>
<p>It starts with a paragraph that is <span>not</span> to be changed.</p>

<div id="text">
<p>Followed by a few few paragraphs in which each each <span>placeholder</span> is expected to be replaced by the user's input.<p>
<p>This should also happen here: <span>another placeholder</span> and here: <span>yet another one</span>.</p>
</div>
```

The `document.querySelectorAll("#text span")` returns all `<spans>` that are found within the specified DOM element with `id="text"` in a "collection". This collection is not an actual JavaScript array, but unlike the HTMLCollection returned by `element.getElementsByTagName()` it has also a method `.forEach()` which I can then directly use to replace each selected element's `.textContent` with the user-entered `inp.value`.